# mirth connect - post db query executes only after checking pre query send status -Error/sent? Advice required

Tags: mirth, hl7-v2, mirth-connect

Basically, I am new to mirth connect. Please give me advice on this.

When I use something like this on Run Post-Process script:

```
try {
  dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mirth','XYZ','XYZ');

  a =$('his_user_id');

  responseStatus=Response.getStatus();

  loger.info(responseStatus);

  if(responseStatus == SENT) {
    var result = dbConn.executeUpdate("UPDATE his_user SET status =0 where id"+a);

    return result;
  }
} 
finally {
  if (dbConn) { 
    dbConn.close();
  }
}
```

---

I am getting the below error:

> SourceSOURCE CODE:
>
> 53: var dbConn;54: 55: try {56:
>
> dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection
>
> ('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mirth',
>   'root','root');57: a =$('his_user_id');58:
>   responseStatus=Response.getStatus();59: 
>   loger.info(responseStatus);60: if(responseStatus == SENT)61:
>
> {62: LINE NUMBER: 58DETAILS:
>
> Java class "com.mirth.connect.userutil.Response" has
>
> no public instance field or method named "getStatus". at
>   0462ff2d-8942-4898-9afb-802bfe68a63d:58
>
> (doScript) at 0462ff2d-8942-4898-9afb-802bfe68a63d:74

---

This is my Pre process script in db writer

```
var dbConn;
try {
  dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mirth','root','root');

  var result = dbConn.executeCachedQuery("SELECT his_user.Id AS his_user_Id, his_user.His_username AS his_user_His_username, his_user.His_useraddress AS his_user_His_useraddress, his_user.status AS his_user_status FROM his_user where his_user.status='1'");

  return result;
} 
finally {
  if (dbConn) { 
    dbConn.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your dbConn to use this instead and it should work...

importPackage(java.sql);

var dbConn= java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection('jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/dbname','user','pass');

If you do not feel like changing your dbConn, you may be able to circumvent that by replacing "dbConn.prepareStatement" with "dbConn.getConnection().prepareStatement". If that doesn't work, you may also need to include "importPackage(java.sql);" at the beginning of your transformer code.